# Value is not updated from other controller via service

Tags: angularjs

I have a controller for menu and controller for each view. What I want to achieve is to add `active` class to menu item so that active menu item get visually selected. To get this working I have created a servide to store current menu item (number). Here's my view.

```
body
    div.menu(ng-controller="menuCtrl")
        ul
            li(ng-class="{selected: menuItem===0}")
                a(href='#/')
                    i.material-icons.medium visibility

            li(ng-class="{selected: menuItem===1}")
                a(href='#/posts')
                    i.material-icons.medium library_books

            li(ng-class="{selected: menuItem===2}")
                a(href='#/categories')
                    i.material-icons.medium loyalty
        span test {{menuItem}} // test menuItem variable


    div.row-fluid
        ng-view
```

Here's `menuCtrl` controller

```
app.controller('menuCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'global', '$interval', function($scope, $http, GLOBAL, $interval ) {
    $scope.menuItem = GLOBAL.menuItem;
}])
```

As you can see I bind variable from service to local `$scope` variable.

And here's my service

```
app.factory( 'global', function( $http ) {
    return {
        menuItem: 0,
    }
})
```

Then in each view controller I add a line to assing certain value to service's `menuItem` like this:

```
app.controller('postsCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'global', '$location', function($scope, $http, GLOBAL, $location ) {
    // ...
    GLOBAL.menuItem = 1;
    // ...
}])
```

The same for all other view controllers, so that `menuItem` is 2,3,4, etc..

The problem is that even if it seems that `menuItem` variable gets changed if I click on several menu items, the value under menu (where I put test comment) is still 0 and, in result, only first menu item have `active` class.

Why?

Comment: This does not answer your question, but I'd encourage you to use some existing solution for this, such as [angular-ui-router-menus](https://github.com/nitintutlani/angular-ui-router-menus).

Answer (score 0):

You should be using [directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) not controllers to manage this sort of thing.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m46vt88a/3/) where the "is-selected" directive makes life easy, tying into your state service without any controller in the middle.

```
  <ul>
    <li is-selected="1">Menu 1</li>
    <li is-selected="2">Menu 2</li>
    <li is-selected="3">Menu 3</li>
    <li is-selected="4">Menu 4</li>
  </ul>
```

On the directive we not only reflect the selected state, but also manage changes to the selected item by using a $watch and injecting a click event handler:

```
myApp.directive('isSelected', ['myService', function(myService) {
  return {
    scope: {},
    link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
      var id = parseInt(attrs.isSelected, 10),           
      unwatch = scope.$watch(
        function() {
          return myService.menu.selected;
        },
        function(val) {       
          if (val == id)
            el.addClass("menuItemSelected")
          else
            el.removeClass("menuItemSelected")
        }),
        dst = scope.$on("$destroy", function() {    
        angular.element(el).off("click");
        unwatch();
        dst();           
      });
      angular.element(el).on("click",function() {
        scope.$apply(function() {myService.menu.selected = id;});       
      });   
    }
  }
}]);
```